# npm install -g create-react-app and tar deprecated

Tags: reactjs

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

added 67 packages in 11s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

I am currently using node version v20
npm version 10.2.3, even I try to update tar using npm i tar@latest and
the issue are still there how could I fix?

I tried to update my node version and tar but once  I update and reinstall create-reacr-app, the problem are still there

```
 npm install tar@latest

added 9 packages, and audited 63 packages in 4s

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details. and
 npm i create-react-app -g
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages in 15s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Comment: It's not about "your" version of tar (and definitely don't install things with `-g`, just install things local to your project, and then run them with `npx` if they come with an executable), it's about the version that create-react-app says it wants because of the dependencies it lists in its own `package.json`. The `create-react-app` project has also been famously out of date for years, and at this point you're probably better off starting with a Next.js app

Comment: FYI, `create-react-app` is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/pull/5487#issuecomment-1409720741).